Can I use the Wish Spell to change my Class ( Wizard 18, Warlock 2 to Wizard 19, Warlock 1)?
I'm currently thinking about how to build an Abjuration Wizard with the new 2024 rules, and the only way to have a reliable (resourceless) source of temporary hp seems to be using the Fiendish Vigor invocation. For that you however need a two level dip into Warlock now, it can't be used taking the Eldritch Adept Feat anymore.
A two level Dip into warlock means giving up on the Epic Boons that a char gets at level 19 - And at the same time, if I ever reached level 19, I wouldn't need the Fiendish Vigor invocation anymore - Once because 12 THP are not a huge thing anymore at level 19, and twice because Spell Mastery allows at will casting of False Life (Sadly not anymore of Misty Step).
The only way to achieve RAW a respec of the one Warlock level that keeps me from the Epic Boon would be a Wish spell - But would that work out? Wishing to change one level of Warlock to one level of Wizard? Or, more in char, to wish to forget all the level 2 abilities one has gathered during the adventures as a warlock that led to being level 2, and instead having gained the knowledge that was still missing to now have the ability to teleport 30 feet whenever one would use a magic action (I used as an example the Boon of Dimensional Travel now, but insert here any other description of another Boon).
Basically I'm asking several questions at once:

Would it be possible RAW to change class using a wish spell?
Would it be reasonable as a DM to allow it?
Would it break the game?
Is it a stupid thing to wish for from a player perspective?
Is it the best way to "keep a character" (of course I could dump the char once I reached level 19, and just make a new level 19 monoclass character - but I like the flavor of having the same char who wished to just have made a different choice about what he learned?
How Would I word this wish in the best way?
Are there other options that I just don't see at the moment?


Are there other options you just aren't seeing at the moment? Yes.
This is something that I would normally say falls under the purview of Downtime (if you're using those optional rules). If your DM is using Downtime rules (which until new rules covering those options are printed are still valid), then my first go-to would be to point at the section that says "your DM might allow different training options," and come up with an agreeable cost to retrain one level you have into another level you have.
If they're not using downtime rules, this may be a harder sell.
Is it a stupid thing to wish for? Eh.
Wishes are what they are. In terms of scope, you're asking for a lateral side-grade (same character level), which is something you may not have another method of achieving.
Any wish other than duplicating an 8th level or lower spell is "risky." Whether or not it's 'stupid' will depend on whether or not you can live with the consequence if you fail the 33% chance to never Wish again that comes with an off-brand Wish.
Would it break the game? Objectively, no.
You aren't asking to become greater than level 20. You're asking to change a class level that you have into another class level (that you also already have some of). If there's no reason a 19wiz/1lock would otherwise break your game, a level 20 character shifting one level to become that shouldn't suddenly trigger the balance police.
Would it be reasonable as a DM to allow it? Per-table basis.
If the DM is comfortable with alternative uses of DT, one might argue that unless you need that class change right that second in combat to save someone's life, it might be unreasonable of them to allow you to do so simply because downtime is a much less risky way to do so.
It's unlikely that this will ever fly if you try to pull it mid-combat, because that sets a nasty precedent of in-battle build flexibility that will bog the game down while you reconfigure your sheet- but there seems little reason you couldn't pull it off in a town or while travelling.
Would it be possible? Yes.
Anything you Wish for is possible. Beware the Monkey's Paw (your DM adjudicates any wish beyond the printed standards.)
How would I word this wish in the best way? Don't.
No really, if you're looking for a Wish that needs an iron-clad contract, don't make the Wish. You've already lost, because you're making the DM contend with your idea rather than making them a part of it.
When you want to color outside the lines like this, give your DM the heads up, and ask them if they'd be receptive in the first place. If you and your DM communicate well over the idea and they like it, you might get away with the wish just expressed as a concept, or maybe some kind of int-based check to word it in a way that doesn't go awry.
The macguffin included in the wish description isn't there for the DM to ruin you; it's there to preserve the fun of the game (which may conveniently ruin you if you ask for something that would otherwise ruin the game through what you think is an iron-clad contract).
P.S. As an Abjurer/Warlock, forget about False Life
Temporary HP don't stack. Armor of Agathys will cost you spell slots (warlock spell, not a wizard spell), but will also synergize with your Arcane Ward, recharging it for more Ward HP on top of your acquired temp HP and the biteback it provides in melee- and because the ward exists, the AoA will provide biteback long beyond its normal life span.
The 2d4+4 temp HP aren't mathematically worth not being able to use AoA while they exist.

I have read through the downtime rules, and if I'm not missing something then there is no indication that the downtime activity can be used to change class - or am I missing something? What page would it be on?

@Quantumwhisp I...am a dumdum. I've been playing on a west march server for two years and they use a custom downtime activity for retraining. I presumed it was an option given in Xanathar's. I went and did some digging- Tasha's provides an option to change your subclass at specific levels. The 2014 PHB had a comment under Downtime that said "your DM might allow different training options." I'll go through and edit this after I've had some sleep. I apologize for the misinformation.

Regarding the PS - It's kind of an ocd of mine to have a char be able to cast some kind of shield or damage preventing spell -as minor as they might be - without limited resources.

+1 for the advice on not word-smithing.  If nothing else, my feeling has always been that "class" and "level" are invisible to the characters---they are tools used by players in order to play, and are not salient features of the in-universe world.  The in-universe version of such a wish would probably be on the lines of "I wish I were more gooder at [things], and I am willing to be more badder at [other things] in exchange."  But trying to write that as a contract which also conveys the desired mechanical outcomes?  Please, no.

@Quantumwhisp I can understand that. I'm not advising you to throw away that principle, but you might want to approach it a bit differently than a Temp HP source on this particular character, so as to not deny yourself the largest benefit (IMO) an abjurer gets from a warlock dip (AoA never works if you have other temp hp, and anything False Life soaks isn't getting AoA biteback). --> Depending on your subrace/backgrounds/feats/campaign, it's possible you might have access to cure wounds as a wizard spell- I think you'd find that much more synergistic.

"The macguffin included in the wish description isn't there for the DM to ruin you; " Historically it was, and like many things a lot of the wording is kept there for backwards compatibility - one could easily argue that the wording there IS intended for the DM to ruin you.

@aslum 1/2 That's also a valid interpretation, but it's a more contentious one than the tables I prefer to pursue. I've always felt the Golden Rule of off-brand Wishes is 'what does this do for the game?' Wishing for a monster to stop existing before you get to it is cheese, and it triggers you being catapulted to 1000 years in the future where its remains have completely disintegrated. Wishing the monster far away when 4/5 party members are dead so you can regroup works, because it preserves the continuation of the game.

@aslum 2/2 Wishing for a character build shift of one level is in the field of things I'd be okay with, because I don't feel it makes narrative sense that a level 20 character can't shift their field of focus, and it's not going to make the game more fun for anyone if I penalize the player by making them level back up to 20 from scratch before the story progresses.

@TheFallen0ne Oh for sure. I was mainly pointing out that historical baggage of wish being confrontational has at least partially been kept through to the current editions. I'm all for "reasonable" wishes being granted as is, where reasonable is interpreted as advancing the story in an interesting way. Personally I wouldn't let OP use a wish that way in my campaign because I'd just let them retrain (likely via some gold spent and them describing a "training montage" of "unlearning" their Warlockian bad habits). They could then use the wish for something else.

@TheFallen0ne the wording of AoA has changed in that regard. It now says :"The spell ends early if you have no Temporary Hit Points." So AoA ist not longer a contraindication. Of course it still only makes sense to use false life if AoA ist low or mit present, but it's Something.

@Quantumwhisp That is an interesting update, and it makes a twilight cleric a particularly good ally (moreso than usual :D). I could see where 2d4+4 temp hp might be useful if your AoA has 1 HP left... but if that happens you're probably in combat, and a level 20 character being attacked with AoA up makes a minimum cast false life over another upcast AoA a hard sell for me, especially since the new AoA is also a Bonus Action instead of False Life's Action... but you're right, it isn't nothing.
